# phpstorm - как описать переменную phpdoc'ом вне класса?

Tags: php, phpstorm

Внутри класса описываю переменную:

```
class Database
{  
    /**
     * @var \PDO
     */
    private $dbh;
}
```

И автоподстветка методов работает:

```
$this->dbh->prepare($sql);
```

**Данный пример (выше) не относится к проблеме ниже!**

Вне класса почему-то не пашет (на скриншоте контроллер, по сути это файл  целиком), phpstorm не видит phpdoc-блок и подсвечивает красным метод объекта "Метод .... не найден." **Как побороть бяку?**

Скринпук

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Укажите конкретно где возникает ошибка и где объявлена аннотация. PhpStorm ругается на метод getResponse в переменной $response? можете привести пример кода \core\Track?

Comment: вот ещё мысль: попробуйте в аннотации указать имя переменной. .`/** @var \core\Track $response */`

Comment: @МихаилРебров так пашет, сенкс. Ответом норм офрмите для зачтения ответа.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте указать в аннотации название переменной

```
/**
 * @var \core\Track $response
 */
$response = new $class($code,$service_id);
```

Внутри метода данная аннотация может располагаться где угодно(не обязательно над объявлением переменной), поэтому PhpStorm по всей видимости игнорирует данные аннотации без название переменной, к которой она должна применяться.

см. https://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/var.html

Также следите за правильностью написания неймспейса(PhpStorm может не отобрать подсказки если ему он не понравился)